# Clarification on Latin Terms for Grammar

Tags: grammar, latin

I'm studying Classical Arabic at the moment from a book written quite some time ago. It uses Latin names for the various grammatical terms and I am having some difficulty in understanding them.

For example, the terms: *nomen substantivium* and *nomen adjectivum*. From what I could gather *nomen* is Latin for noun? If so then what is *nomen adjectivum*? I know this is referring to adjectives but what is *nomen* doing prefixed to *adjectivum*?

Also what is the difference between *nomen demonstrativum* and *nomen conjunctivium*?

Comment: It looks like you're asking more than one thing here - you might like to split these into separate questions.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Terms like *nomen substantivum* (i.e. *substantive*) and *nomen adjectivum* (i.e. *adjective*) refer to Latin grammar, not English. Did you mean to ask at [Latin.SE](http://latin.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Curiously enough, I found references in [A grammar of the Arabic language - Volume 1 (**1874**)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WiQUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA120&dq=%22The+nomen+demonstrativum,+or+Demonstrative+Pronoun%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22The%20nomen%20demonstrativum%2C%20or%20Demonstrative%20Pronoun%22&f=false) to *the nomen demonstrativum, or **Demonstrative Pronoun** and the nomen conjunctivium, or **Relative Pronoun***. But this isn't about ***English***.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Latin and/or antiquated Arabic-focused texts

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm ... I'm inclined to regard it as legitimate, since these terms were the stock-in-trade of grammatical discourse in English, too.

Comment: @choster, I wasn't aware of Latin.SE. I will post Latin grammar related questions there next time.

Comment: @StoneyB: But isn't it "domain specific" terminology? Even if the domain happens to be English, it's not relevant to terminology *currently* used in the domain "Study of English Grammar" or whatever we call it. I accept that obscure terminology in *current* use within that particular domain is On Topic (whereas obscure usages in particle physics wouldn't be). But there has to be a limit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What's "current use" got to do with it? Do we prohibit questions about Eliot's or Joyce's or Byron's or Shakespeare's or Chaucer's use of terms which have lost currency?

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, Shakespeare (and even Chaucer, although less so) *are* "English Usage" - or at least they make important contributions to the language as we use (or might encounter) it today. But to me this hopelessly obsolete Latin terminology is just specialist domain *history* (or antiquarianism! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classical Latin grammarians did not distinguish between adjectives and nouns as 'parts of speech': what we call adjectives could be used as nouns, and adjectives declined the same way nouns did (only in three genders!), so they called them both  *nomina*, our nouns. What they *did* distinguish (in a very modern way) was *uses* of the words: a *nomen substantivum* (substantive noun) was a noun employed to designate an 'entity', something with 'substance', and a *nomen adjectivum* (adjective noun) was a noun 'set down next to' a substantive as a modifier.

Similarly, a *nomen demonstrativum*, which 'pointed to' another noun, was what we call a 'demonstrative pronoun', and a *nomen conjunctivum*, which 'joined' a noun to a clause about it, was what we call a 'relative pronoun'.